# Deleting from multiple tables in SQL older than x amount of days

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's my situation. We have a database here that just has a bunch of logging going on.  We have a single job setup to purge anything in the log older than 30 days on that table…that was easy to setup.

So my question is this, now they want some sort of script or stored procedure to delete everything older than 30 days in all tables in that database. Do you know of anything that can do this?  I’ve been scouring the net for hours now looking through stored procedures and queries not really getting anywhere. I created a query that does this individually to all the tables in that database but they want something more dynamic for when they add and delete tables to that database so we don’t have to keep going in and editing the query.

So it would be a stored procedure that would basically do this to all the tables in the database

```
USE TESTLog;

delete FROM TestLogTable WHERE Date < GETDATE() – 30
```

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

**UPDATE:**
So I talked to a friend she she recommended using a stored procedure (below), but I can't seem to get the exec to run with the deletes. Print works just fine. But when I change to the EXEC (SQL) it does not work.

```
USE [TEST_DELETE]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

--Creates stored procedure
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TableCleanup]
AS
    --Code starts here for table cleanup--
    DECLARE @myCursor cursor;
    DECLARE @tableName CHAR(100),
            @sql CHAR(300)

BEGIN
    SET @myCursor = CURSOR FOR
        SELECT rtrim(table_schema) + '.' + rtrim(Table_Name) as tableName
        FROM information_schema.tables Where table_type = 'Base Table'

  OPEN @myCursor

  FETCH NEXT FROM @myCursor INTO @tableName

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
      SET @sql = 'delete FROM ' + rtrim(@tableName )+ ' WHERE Date < GETDATE() – 30'
      EXEC (@sql)

      FETCH NEXT FROM @myCursor INTO @tableName             
  END   

  CLOSE @myCursor
  DEALLOCATE @myCursor
END
```

Comment: Doing this blindly to every table in your database seems an absolutely awful idea. Do you have that column in every single table? What about lookup tables? What about RI? You would have to delete children before the parent rows.

Comment: What they want to delete is from the DATE COLUMN in all tables.  I'm not sure why, they just want this done.  Most of the tables have the DATE column but a few have STARTDATE and ENDDATE and they said they don't care about those tables...only the ones with the DATE column.

Comment: You can't delete a column, you delete rows. Are you wanting to set the DATE column to NULL? You are going to have to query sys.columns and find tables with the column names you want and then run a query against those tables.

Comment: Sorry you are correct, thats what I meant...rows not columns.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, assuming that the Date field exists in all the tables in that database

```
USE TESTLog;
GO
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DELETE FROM ? WHERE [Date] < GETDATE() - 30'
GO
```

Comment: I tried this, but got  Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '–'.

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'Date'.

Comment: Would that message above be from the tables that do not have DATE column?

Comment: That's because Date is a reserved word (Horrible column name). You have to wrap it in square brackets. [Date]

Comment: I'm definitely not arguing with you on this.  I did not design this database, it is a mess...i'm doing the best i can with what I have to work with.  It's a touchy subject when trying to tell a team of 10-12 developers how to create these Dbs.

Comment: @jcosley, yes it looks like there is a table that doesn't have date column, try running `'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ? WHERE [Date] < GETDATE() - 30'` and see which table it is throwing error on

Comment: Also still got  Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid column name 'Date'  when putting it in brackets.

Comment: it completed with errors this time when running that new select statement

Answer (score 0):

Query the master for all table names.  Then apply the table names to your SQL

Comment: Well that's what I thought I could do...something like this..but hasn't worked or panned out yet.  USE TEST_DELETE;
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE Date < GETDATE() - 30

Answer (score 0):

You need to query sys.columns to figure out which tables have a column named Date. This will generate the delete statements for you. I would use stuff to generate this as a list and then execute the whole thing using sp_executesql.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'delete from [' + OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) + '] where [Date] < DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE());'
from sys.columns
where name = 'Date'

select @SQL
exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Ok so that query produced the results i'm looking for with the tables that have those columns/rows.  What would i do, add that sp_executesql to the end of the query?

Comment: @jcosley I edited my answer to include the code to execute this.

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't work gave me    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'exec'

Comment: Comment out the exec and examine the contents of @SQL.